# Rails 3 Array in HighCharts - my brain will explode

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I have a do loop:

```
<% @currentfruit.each do |apples| %>
  <%= apples.prices %>
<% end %>
```

It displays, as expected, a line of all apple prices ever entered in the model. I want to take this data, and plot each entry that is displayed in Highcharts, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Do I put this into an array somehow, do I run an entirely different query all together? What's the best way to accomplish this?

UPDATE:

Below Ryan's answer works great:

```
@currentfruit.map(&:prices).to_json
```

It displays an array of all the prices ever entered, just what I wanted. But when I plot them in Highcharts:

```
data: [ <%= @currentfruit.map(&:prices).to_json]
```

It only shows one data point on the chart, even though the whole array of values is displayed up above. How can I get all the values in the array to plot on the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you'll want to put this into a JSON array, which you can do with this:

```
@currentfruit.map(&:prices).to_json
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I'm really new and haven't seen/used the .map method before, I'll have to learn more about that. So it displays the list of data just fine as an array, but I'm still not sure how to plot it. If I assign it a variable, then plot that variable, it only displays one of the data points in the chart. Any ideas?

Comment: Ryan, I figured out that the output already put brackets around it, and when I put it into Highcharts, there were already brackets there, making them double. I just took one set away and it worked. Thanks again!